# How do I view the meta data for visual studio files?

Tags: visual-studio, metadata

I have two nearly-identical visual studio solutions and I am trying to determine the author of the files in each project  to figure out which is which.

How can this be done?

Comment: Files are files. Why do you think there's some extra metadata?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using source control, like TFS or SVN, the proper place to check for the author of the files is in there.

Comment: It's doubtful that the author information is stored anywhere, then.